# Trying to get mailbox using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to get my mails using Microsoft Graph, but I am getting this error

*Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed*

This is the code I am using I found on internet

```
        try
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
            "TenantId",
            "ClientId",
            "ClientSecret",
            new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

            // Define a new Microsoft Graph service client.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);

            // Get the e-mails for a specific user.
            var result = await graphClient.Users["<<MyMail>>"].MailboxSettings.GetAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: look a permissions issue What permissions do you have on Microsoft Graph for Mail.* ?

Comment: You want to get [MailboxSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or you want to [list all the mails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: I had the wrong permissions, now it's working, thanks!

Comment: What permissions did you have to add @EmmanuelFrias? I'm facing the same error and I added all possible mail related permissions but still not working for me. I also added another user to the user list by invitation feature and tried with that user too.